# Set Double Array Equal to Return Value without Declaring Dimensions

Tags: c, arrays, declaration, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program that uses a dimensional array.  I have a function that will return a two dimensional array of floats.  The function looks like this:

```
float[][] convert() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Then, in a in a main method, I want to set a table equal to that array, but I'm not sure how I can do that without already knowing the dimensions I want.  Ideally, I'd have a line like:

```
float table[][] = convert();
```

Is there a way to get around having to know the dimensions of the table in the main method?  My program only keeps track of the length inside the convert function.

Comment: How do you make that even compile?

Answer (score 1):

you can use array 2D with pointers doubvle pointers

```
float **table = convert();
```

into the function `convert()` you can allocate memory(2d array) with size you want and return it in the function

Comment: No you cannot, because they aren't the same.

Comment: it's a suggestion as an alternate solution for 2d array

Comment: 2D arrays don't implicitly convert to double pointers, you know that right?

Comment: @TonyTheLion indedd as I said is an alternative solution